# how to create JMS queues in run-time using Spring JMS support?

Tags: java, spring, jms, spring-jms

I need to dynamically create JMS queues during runtime. Is it possible to do this with the Spring JMS support (JmsTemplate?)? and how? code examples or references would be greatly appreciated.

Update: 
It turns out that it is not possible to create physical destinations through the JMS API, so I assume that is not possible in JmsTemplate as well. However, I found that I can use the temporary queues, but still don't know how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some brokers (such as ActiveMQ) can create queues on the fly when they are used.

Others require pre-provisioning.

Temporary queues may not be what you want - they are "owned" by the connection and go away when the connection is closed.